Reference Request: Partially mixing and partially rigid transformation
I'm looking for the reference to who originally proved the existence of transformations with are $\alpha$-partially mixing and $(1-\alpha)$-partially rigid.
Given a probability-preserving system $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$, the system is $\alpha$-partially mixing if $\liminf \mu(T^{n}A \cap B) \geq \alpha \mu(A)\mu(B)$ for all $A,B \in \mathcal{B}$ and at least $\beta$-partially rigid if there exists a sequence $\{ t_{n} \}$ such that $\liminf \mu(T^{t_{n}}A \cap A) \geq \beta\mu(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}$.
Relatedly, I'm looking also for the reference to the first proof of the existence of partially rigid transformations for all $\beta \in (0,1)$.
Thanks!

This is the first reference I'm aware of that explicitly constructs transformations with sequences that are $\alpha$-mixing and $(1-\alpha)$-rigid:  https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/relay-station?mr=1012984 .  It may be the earliest reference that constructs $\beta$-rigid transformations for any $\beta \in (0,1)$.  See this reference: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.2622.  The notion of $\beta$-rigidity was understood well before the 1980s.  It was known that Chacon's transformation is partially rigid.  In J.R. Baxter's thesis (1969), it was proved that a $\beta$-rigid transformation where $\beta > \frac{1}{2}$ has singular spectrum.  There is a Friedman/Ornstein paper, On Partially Mixing Transformations (1971), which appears to be the first explicit construction on partially mixing, non-mixing transformations.  Ran out of room in the comments section, so writing this as an answer.  Hope this helps!

Thank you much!  That's exactly what I was looking for.

You're welcome!
